# laravel-shopify-API-wrapper: Pass charge to shopify

Tags: php, laravel, shopify

I'm using [this shopify api code](https://github.com/joshrps/laravel-shopify-API-wrapper).  I've managed to get my app to install but now when I try to set up a charge for my app when I make the call I get this error:

```
Exception in api.php line 512:
ERROR #3: <url> malformed
```

This is my code:

```
        $charge_params = array (
        'recurring_application_charge' => array (
            'name' =>  'Name Of Charge',
            'price' => 10,
            'return_url' => 'https://dev.shopify.com/show_products/', // also tried escaping the url so https:\/\/dev.shopify.com\/show_products\/
            'test' => true
        )
    );

 $charge = $sh->call(['URL' => '/admin/recurring_application_charges.json', 'METHOD' => 'GET', 'DATA' => ['charge_params' => $charge_params]], false);
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I suspect it might be the way the `$charge_params` is being passed in.  There's no documentation on how to pass the charge data through that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to pass the full URL and pass the charge array slightly differently.  Also changed the method to "POST".

This code did the trick:

```
  $charge = $sh->call([
'URL' => 'https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/recurring_application_charges.json',
'METHOD' => 'POST',
'DATA' => array (
  'recurring_application_charge' => array (
    'name' =>  'Name Of Charge',
    'price' => 10,
    'return_url' => 'https://dev.shopify.com/show_products/',
    'test' => true
  )
)
], false);
print_r($charge);
exit;
```

This returned the following:

```
stdClass Object ( [recurring_application_charge] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 2655692 [name] => Name Of Charge [api_client_id] => 1182423 [price] => 10.00 [status] => pending [return_url] => https://dev.shopify.com/show_products/ [billing_on] => [created_at] => 2016-08-03T13:50:11-04:00 [updated_at] => 2016-08-03T13:50:11-04:00 [test] => 1 [activated_on] => [trial_ends_on] => [cancelled_on] => [trial_days] => 0 [decorated_return_url] => https://dev.shopify.com/show_products/?charge_id=2655692 [confirmation_url] => https://mystore.myshopify.com/admin/charges/2655692/confirm_recurring_application_charge?signature=BAhpA8yFKA%3D%3D--8f87b4bd0d3cb9a588dfcb1566572731c0118776 ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just trying to recall what I did on an old project, here is how I handled it, I am using the following package for this https://github.com/phpish/shopify:

```
$connection = shopify\client($shop, Config::get('shopify.app_api_key'), $token);

$billing = $connection('POST /admin/recurring_application_charges.json', [
            'recurring_application_charge' => [
            'name' => 'Standard',
            'price' => '5.0',
            'return_url' => Config::get('app.url') . '/shopify/billing',
            'test' => Config::get('shopify.test_mode')
        ]]);
```

Not sure if this is any help to you...

Comment: Just tried your data structure for the charge part but no luck unfortunately.  Nice idea though and thanks anyway.